# spreadsheet: use equation to calculate value

Tags: gnumeric

I have a simple table in Gnumeric (but I expect there should be a general solution for all spredsheets). Column B contains numbers (input), and column C should contain values calculated using my equation. For the first cell, the equation is `=(B6-C5)*C4`. Now I want to drag (expand) the equation down the column, so that all the cells are populated with the solutions. The problem is, the cells `C5` and `C4` should stay static, only the `B` cells should go from `B6` to `B_infinity`.... But unfortunately, gnumeric increments all cells, ie

```
=(B6-C5)*C4
=(B7-C6)*C5
=(B8-C7)*C6
...
```

whereas, I need the equation to be:

```
=(B6-C5)*C4
=(B7-C5)*C4
=(B8-C5)*C4
...
```

How can I tell Gnumeric what I want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the cell reference to be abosolute, with a `$` symbol:

```
=(B6-C5)*$C$4
```

Answer (score 1):

If excel is the same as gnumeric, you need to freeze your references. For the first formula, use:

```
=(B6-$C$5)*$C$4
```

After that, fill down this formula and it should be doing what you expected it to do.